# how to add file information (product version) to jar files?

Tags: java, jar, fileinfo

I want a product version number to appear in a jar files file information.

Like for .exe, .dll and .sys files.
I'm not asking for a "manifest" solution where you first have to decompress but for a file information (right mouse click -> details -> "product name", "product version", etc.)
Is that possible?

Doesn't matter if a solution will only work for Windows because my jar file is only compatible with Windows anyway...

Regards,
Uwe

Comment: In the manifest. Manifests have nothing to do with decompression, unless the JAR file is compressed, which is a separate issue.

Comment: @Uwe Anderson, have you found any solution